# Convert cell array to table by retaining the header

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert a cell array to a table so that it retains the header of the table. How can I do that in Matlab? 
I tried using cell2table, it works, but adds additional header.

my cell array:

```
txt: 3x2

'type'  'no'

 'A'    '1'

 'B'     '2'
```

When I use cell2table(txt), I get

```
     txt1         txt2    
_____________    ____ 
    'type'       'no'
      'A'         '1'
      'B'         '2'
```

but I expect

```
    type          no    
_____________    ____ 
      'A'         '1'
      'B'         '2'
```

Can anyone please suggest how to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the headers using the `'VariableNames'` property.

```
>> cell2table(txt(2:end,:),'VariableNames',txt(1,:))
ans =
  2×2 table
    type    no 
    ____    ___
    'A'     '1'
    'B'     '2'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :)